# PDN analysis of PCB - Max. conductor current density and max. via current density

Tags: pcb-design, altium, conductors

I just started using the PDN analyzer tool of Altium and am getting acquainted with it right now. While the tool with its visualization windows is quite useful, I am confused about what values of maximum conductor current density and maximum via current density (A/mm<sup>2</sup>) I should feed into the settings dialogue box.

The internet has a few conflicting answers which aren't helping. So, can anyone over here who has used similar tools extensively, comment on what factors should be considered while deciding these values (no. of layers, thickness of copper, etc.)? Is there any formula which can be used? I really want to know the underlying logic.

Comment: Depending on your board design and requirements, you might benefit from the following, more specific standard: IPC-2152 – Standard for Determining Current-Carrying Capacity in Printed Board Design

Comment: Agree. A/mm2 is not an interesting number. It’s so much depending on the stack, close copper planes etc. 2152 takes these factors more in account. For example, a short intertrace with a small width (by the calculator too small) can perform very nice, although it’s A/mm2 is too high. Because this intertrace is cooled by the joined traces.

Answer (score 1):

> If you know how much current you need to conduct through your PCB’s copper, what your maximum ambient service temperature is likely to be, and the maximum temperature your trace can reach, you can use the formulas from IPC-2221 to calculate the appropriate trace width.

There are some online calculators available to aid you in doing that. This Altium resource will walk you through the details: [Copper Current Density for Simulations, The Quick and Dirty Way](https://resources.altium.com/p/copper-current-density-simulations-quick-and-dirty-way)